# WSL2 Docker connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp:

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, wsl-2

When running `docker-compose up` on my WSL-2, which runs a single container `image: ibmcom/ibp-microfab`.

Firstly starting and attaching to the container is successfull eg.

```
Starting testmicrofab ... done
Attaching to testmicrofab 
testmicrofab | [   microfabd] 2021/05/31 10:41:18 Starting Microfab ...
testmicrofab | [   microfabd] 2021/05/31 10:41:18 Loaded state
testmicrofab | [   microfabd] 2021/05/31 10:41:18 Creating endorsing organization org1 
...
```

But than after some time I see only the following WARN log looping and preventing a succesfull start of the microfab

```
...
testmicrofab | [    org1peer] 2021-05-31 10:43:04.061 UTC [peer.blocksprovider] DeliverBlocks -> WARN 068 Could not connect to ordering service: could not dial endpoint 'orderer-api.127-0-0-1.nip.io:8080': failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp: lookup orderer-api.127-0-0-1.nip.io on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host" channel=channel1
testmicrofab | [    org2peer] 2021-05-31 10:43:04.087 UTC [peer.blocksprovider] DeliverBlocks -> WARN 041 Could not connect to ordering service: could not dial endpoint 'orderer-api.127-0-0-1.nip.io:8080': failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp: lookup orderer-api.127-0-0-1.nip.io on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host" channel=channel1
testmicrofab | [    org1peer] 2021-05-31 10:43:04.102 UTC [peer.blocksprovider] DeliverBlocks -> WARN 042 Could not connect to ordering service: could not dial endpoint 'orderer-api.127-0-0-1.nip.io:8080': failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp: lookup orderer-api.127-0-0-1.nip.io on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host" channel=channel2
...
```

##### docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  microfabtest:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: ibmcom/ibp-microfab
    container_name: testmicrofab 
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    environment:
      HLF_CONF: $HLF_CONF
    volumes:
      - microfabdata:/opt/microfab/data
```

###### HLF_CONF

Basically defines two organisations `org1` `org2` and two channels `channel1` and `channel2` both of which are endorsed by `[org1, org2]`

###### Versions:

- WSL-2: 20.04
- Docker: Docker version 20.10.2, build 20.10.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.2
- Docker-compose: docker-compose version 1.25.0

Comment: Please, share your docker compose file.

Comment: Added my docker-compose.yaml

Comment: It's failing to resolve `orderer-api.127-0-0-1.nip.io` to an ip address embedded in the hostname itself which is what nip.io does. It's sending the DNS request here `127.0.0.11:53` which I assume is part of the docker stack. Does Microfab work for you outside of using compose ?